# How to modify the devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

As the basic devise gem has the four parameters,i want to modify `username` with `email`

**Here is what i tried to do**

`step-1` - `rails g migration add_username_hrs username:string`

`step-2` - `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

`step-3` - `updated add_username_hrs.rb`

```
class AddUsernameHrs < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
         add_column :hrs, :username, :string
    end
    def self.down
         remove_column :hrs, :username, :string
    end
 end
```

`step-4` - `Replace **:email** with **:username**`

```
<%= f.label :username %><br /> 
<%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true , :placeholder => "Username" %>
```

**Error**

```
undefined method `username' for #<Hr:0x2951c88>
```

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Devise, you need to reboot your Rails server after your migration so that ActiveRecord adds the `username` method to your `Hr` class.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the `config.authentication_keys` line in `config/initializers/devise.rb`. Replace the `:email` with `:username`.

There's more info in the Devise wiki - [How To: Allow users to sign in with something other than their email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

According to your steps, you migrated your database before updating the migration file. If that is the case, you'll need to rollback your migration and then run it again. You will also want to temporarily comment out the remove_column line in self.down. This is because that column does not exist.

1. Comment out `remove_column :hrs, :username, :string`
2. run `bundle exec rake db:rollback`
3. Uncomment line from step 1
4. run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: I have done same as before..can you please from initial .thanks